# No search indexes bound via Haystack using Haystackbrowser

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-haystack

Has someone ever used this tool for all-text searching? I just installed this to my project and the installation seems working fine. But when I clicked the haystackbrowser button in my admin page, it returned to a webpage which said no search indexes bound via Haystack. I checked my project and I am sure that I created the search_index file.
Could someone please help me? Thanks!

Comment: Did you run `manage.py rebuild_index`?

Comment: Thank you for your helping. There is new issue, I solved the problem I mentioned, but when I do the 'python3 manage.py rebuild_index'. It shows that:

 'GenesIndex' object has no attribute 'fields'

GeneIndex is the class what I created. Do you know what's going on?

Comment: Please open a new question then, with more information about this problem (e.g. the `GenesIndex` code).

Comment: Thank you for your help! Now I figured it out, again, I am appreciate for you kind help!

Comment: No problem, great that you figured it out!